# javascript: Syntax to capture both string value of element name and element

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am  getting hung up on how to go back and forth between the string value of the id of an element and element itself.  I believe the problem involves syntax but cannot get it right.  I would like to pass one parameter in javascript (in this case "title" and use it as a string and an element as follows to make a title disappear and an edit title box appear.

html

```
//note this html is actually written to page by another javascript function
<span id="title">Title</span><span id="titleedit"></span><img src="edit.gif" onclick="editTitle('title');">
```

If I leave out apostrophes around title I can get it to work as an element in following but then it does not work as a string.

javascript

```
function editTitle(field) {
//using field as string only works if parameter in above is in apostrophes
var fieldedit = field+"edit"
var editstring = '<input type="text" name="title" onclick="saveTitle();">save';
document.getElementById('fieldedit').innerHTML = "editstring";
//using as element only works if above has no apostrophes
field.style.display="none";
}
```

Thanks for suggesting how to accomplish both tasks...make title disappear and titleedit appear passing just word title.  (The reason I want to pass title as parameter as there are a whole bunch of other fields to edit that I'd like to pass as one parameter each.)

Comment: Getting forth: `element.id` and back: `document.getElementById(idstring)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `document.getElementById('fieldedit')`, you're saying "the element with "fieldedit" as the id". What you want is "The element with the contents of the variable fieldedit as the id.

Give it a shot with `document.getElementById(fieldedit).innerHTML = editstring;`.

**Update**:

There is also a problem with this line:

```
var editstring = "<input type="text" name="title" onclick="saveTitle();">save";
```

Try escaping your quotes, or using a mixture of single and double quotes. For example:

```
var editstring = '<input type="text" name="title" onclick="saveTitle();">save';
```

**Update 2**:

To obtain a reference to the element with `id="title"`:

```
var field = document.getElementById('title');
```

Now that *field* refers to that element, you can use:

```
field.style.display = 'none';
```

You can also do it all in one line:

```
document.getElementById('title').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: You're right that is an error but I wrote it down wrong.  The deeper problem is if I leave out apostrophes in sending "title" I cannot add "edit" to it as it is not a string but the element itself.

Comment: By itself, `title` is not an element, even if there exists an element with that id. So, you *do* want to send 'title' as a string (with apostrophes).

Comment: Yes, sorry, another error you caught.  If I put title in apostrophes, I get the title as a string.  But then it does not allow me to hide it as an element, ie field.style.display="none" does not compute.  So how would I get it to recognize that field is not a string but refers to the element "title".  Seems like it should work but does not.

Comment: Update 2 should answer your question.

Comment: What ended up working was document.getElementById(fieldedit).style.display = 'none'; where fieldedit was a variable (therefore no apostrophes) created from var fieldedit = field+"dit";  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('fieldedit').innerHTML = "editstring";`

Shouldn't that be

`document.getElementById(fieldedit).innerHTML = editstring;` ?

You want to get the span with the id "titleedit" and insert the input element stored in `editstring`, if I understand your question.